# How to get red distance lines in storyboard Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

Watching a tutorial and it looks like the guy is holding down a button to show the distance between his selected view and what's around it.
[image]

I've tried command, option, control, and every other button I can think might work.  What button needs to be held to get these lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By pressing option key only on your keyboard.

Select an element, and move the mouse while pressing the option key, it will show the red lines with the distances.

Hovering over another element will show you the distance between the selected element and that element.